# Best filesystem for accidental external disk disconnects?

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, macos

I have an external disk that is connected to the monitor that acts as a hub and then to my laptop.

I rarely copy data to/from disk, but it's really convenient to just have it there when I am at my desk. All the data is backed up to remote server using backblaze in case the disk dies.

Because I move around with my laptop a lot I am afraid I will forget to eject the disks and corrupt the data.

Any advice on how to make this experience as seamless as possible? Which filesystem to use so the chances of data corruption are lowest?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using `autofs` with a short timeout to umount the filesystem when it's idle?

Comment: Fear not. With modern journaling file systems it is not very likely to cause a damage that can't be recovered easily. You can further reduce it by a background job calling `sync` periodicly.